# I have a logic question regarding login "Remember me", JWT, and everything related

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, authentication, jwt

This is a SQL, Express/Node and ReactJS stack.
I'm using JsonWebToken.

It would seem other people have their Login form set so - if a user logs in, and they have the "Remember Me" checkbox checked, they'd store the JWT (token) in the browser's 'localStorage'.
Then they retrieve localStorage each time they go to make a request and throw it in the authorization header.

The logic question here, is when a user leaves my web app... then returns later. Do I perform a check with localStorage.get('jwtToken') when  component mounts? 
And if it exists, attempt a JWT login (instead of username+password login) and open the token on Node server to get the user's ID out of it? If user's ID exists, get their info out of the DB and return it to the browser?

Does that sound right?
It just feels a little strange or vulnerable.

Comment: The token is signed with a secret and it will be checked if it is valid for every request that get sent to server, so yes it is safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take JWT and get the user data and if the token gets expired, you can just redirect user to login page.